# Linux From Scratch 11 can not verify any SSL certificates

Tags: wget, openssl, ssl, lfs, gnutls

I have built an LFS 11.0 system and installed wget from the BLFS book. I also have openssl and gnutls installed, but whenever do wget for a site with ssl, it says it can't verify the cert. It does work if I add the `--no-check-certificate` option, though. I also have installed lynx with ssl support and it says `This client does not support https urls.` I think it is missing SSL root CA certs, but I do not know where to get then, or where to put them when I get them.

EDIT: Internet connectivity does work, and I can ping sites and wget/lynx with http:// urls.

Comment: `it says it can't verify the cert` doesn't really provide much information. To get help it's best to include **actual** command and responses/output.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I solved it, I had not correctly installed the certificates from the BLFS book.